# ls | grep regex, ignore files with .tab,

Tags: grep, regex

I know some regex but I don't know how to get this to work.
I want to list all files that don't have .tab. and don't have ~ at the end of the filename and aren't a .o (or .bin)

I can list all the files that have .tab. by writing

```
ls | grep .tab.
```

However I cannot figure out how to make it ignore those files and list everything else. I tried

```
ls | grep [^(.tab.)]
```

but got an error and thought my final regex would be

```
ls | grep ([^(.tab.)]|.o$|.bin$)
```

But I've never done much regex so I am sure the final is wrong even if the syntax was right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I would do this would depend on the context.  If this wasn't for a script, and I just wanted to see this, I would be okay with using ls:

```
ls -a | egrep -v '(tab|\.o$|\.bin$|~$)'
```

If in a script, I would use a loop:

```
for file in *; do
#file $file in .* *; do   -- To Include dot (hidden files)                     
   if ! egrep -q '(tab|\.o$|\.bin$|~$)' <<<$file; then
      echo $file
   fi
done
```

You could add another if test with -f if you only want regular files and not directories.  If you want to do this recursively, you could use GNU find with a -regex test and posix-egrep.  But take into account the fact that this regex will match the full pathname relative to the directory you searched in.

Another nice option is extended globs if you have support for it, see Dennis's answer.

Comment: You can also use fancy =~ regex tests with certain shells, really, there are tons of ways to do this :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `-v`/`--invert-match` option makes grep output lines that do *not* match. So:

```
ls | grep -v .tab.
```

or

```
ls | grep --invert-match .tab.
```

in your case.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s extglob
ls -l !(*.bin|*.o|*~|*.tab.*)
```

Comment: This is Bash-specific. In ksh, no option needs to be set. For zsh you need to do `setopt kshglob`.

Answer (score 0):

`ls | egrep -v (.tab|.o$|.bin$)`

should do it.  egrep is basically grep -E, which supports 'extended' regex, so stuff like (x|y) works.

Comment: Need to escape the dots, this would exclude files such as 'bar.foo'

Comment: You're correct, that's what I get for doing regex before coffinating myself ;)

Comment: Ha ha fool! I never post before my second cup! *glugglugglug*

Comment: Definitions, just in time for Halloween: "coffinating" - What a vampire does just before sunrise. "coffeenating" - What a vampire does just before going to "work" (euphamistically speaking).

Comment: Umm...I did that on purpose, in the spirit of Halloween ;)

I seriously need more coffee...